# Register BHO (or Toolbar) per user in HKCU

Tags: internet-explorer, bho

Can IE BHO (or Toolbar) be registered at HKCU level (instead HKLM)? I have found some contradicting information and my personal tests have failed. So a pointer to a definite answer would be great. Is the location in HKCU different to HKLM or is it plain and simple not doable?

I am also happy if this is doable for a particular IE version only (e.g. only IE9+ or similar). [This discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/2cf1a0c0-ce10-4f2d-8e8f-a48a66bd07b4/) seems to indicate this is not possible but that's from 1.5 year ago.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your BHO in **HKLM** first.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects\{GUID}
DEFAULT='Your BHOName'
NoExplorer=1
```

And then put your bho dll specific data in **HKCR** instead of **HKLM**.

```
HKCR\CLSID\{GUID}\
HKCR\CLSID\{GUID}\Programmable
HKCR\CLSID\{GUID}\InprocServer32
HKCR\CLSID\{GUID}\TypeLib
HKCR\CLSID\{GUID}\Version
```